# How to call custom callback function in CreateThread?

Tags: c, winapi, createthread

I want to use `CreateThread` function but with my own custom callback function, this is how I am using it

```
 HANDLE handle = CreateThread(0,0,custom_function, NULL,0,NULL);
```

declaration of `custom_function`

```
DWORD custom_function(void)
{
    printf("Hello from callback function");
}
```

the warning I get

```
main.c:154:37: warning: passing argument 3 of 'CreateThread' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]    
  154 |         handle = CreateThread(0, 0, custom_function, NULL, 0, NULL);
      |                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                     |
      |                                     DWORD (*)(void) {aka long unsigned int (*)(void)}
In file included from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/winbase.h:29,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/windows.h:70,
                 from rce.c:3:
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/processthreadsapi.h:279:127: note: expected 'LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE' {aka 'long unsigned int (*)(void *)'} but argument is of type 'DWORD (*)(void)' {aka 'long unsigned int (*)(void)'}
  279 |   WINBASEAPI HANDLE WINAPI CreateThread (LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes, SIZE_T dwStackSize, LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE lpStartAddress, LPVOID lpParameter, DWORD dwCreationFlags, LPDWORD lpThreadId);
      |                                                                                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: You can do whatever you want in your function, but the signature must match the one specified by `CreateThread`. Your custom function has wrong return type and wrong parameter list. To fix this, just use the signature that is expected: `long unsigned int (*)(void *)`. You can use `DWORD` as this seems to be same as `long unsigned int` but you must take a `void*` instead of your `void` parameter list.

Comment: @Gerhardh could you elaborate more I don't understand how the final struct of the function should look like

Comment: It should look like this: `DWORD custom_function(void* argument)`

Comment: The `void*` argument to the thread procedure can be used to pass arbitrary data into the newly created thread. It can be anything a client needs to pass along, an integral value or a pointer to an arbitrary structure. Also make sure that your thread procedure has the correct calling convention. A C compiler will not warn you about a mismatch (unlike a C++ compiler).

Comment: @IInspectable can you provide any link for the correct procedure, i am having trouble figure out how to execute the body of `custom_function`

Comment: The documentation for [`CreateThread`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createthread) has a link to the [`ThreadProc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms686736(v=vs.85)). There's also a section called [creating threads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-threads) that explains things in more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the warning is telling you is that the parameter to the callback function needs to be a `void*` (or LPVOID if using Windows API types).

If POSIX threads are familiar, this is not so different - CreateThread allows you to pass a void pointer to custom data as parameter to the callback. But you don't *have* to use it.

The callback should correctly be written as:

```
DWORD WINAPI custom_function (LPVOID lpParam);
```

`WINAPI` specifies that `__stdcall` calling convention should be used. This might be required since this function is to be called from the OS and not from your C program (which probably uses `__cdecl` calling convention).

As for executing, please note that CreateThread gives you the option to create the thread suspended (asleep) or running.

Comment: With the exception of variable argument lists, no-one uses `__cdecl`.

Comment: @IInspectable Older MSVC did or otherwise MS wouldn't insist on typing `WINAPI` all over the place.

Comment: The calling convention isn't a property of a compiler. It's part of the platform's ABI. And [`__stdcall` is the calling convention of the Win32 API](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040108-00/?p=41163), and has always been. If you're talking about *"older"* then that's 16-bit Windows. Microsoft doesn't exactly insist that you type `WINAPI` everywhere. It's just that if you don't specify the calling convention, then you'll inherit the compiler's default. Which may or may not match.

Comment: @IInspectable Actually I have no idea what you are on about. MSVC 19.32 for x86 32 bit: `int (__cdecl *ptr)(void) = main;` compiles fine, `int (__stdcall *ptr)(void) = main;` does not. It is clearly using `__cdecl`. https://godbolt.org/z/38Wa9Yz3e

Comment: That's the language support library's startup code, not the OS. Microsoft's implementation uses `__cdecl`, for whatever reason (presumably because someone way into the last millennium made assumptions). If that makes you happy, let me take the initial statement back and replace it with this one: "No-one uses `__cdecl` out of free will."